# Where can I get free or sample open edx exportable courses?

Tags: openedx, edx

Any idea where can I get a list of free / sample open edx courses to populate on my app? I need to add at least a hundred sample courses as for my boss' requirements. Tried searching but stumbled only to one course from MIT.

Comment: I do not think there is a place to get hundreds of free courses out there. If you just need sample courses, then get one course and write a script to generate multiple courses.

Comment: @IsankaWijerathne they actually need actual free courses with real lessons and stuff and different uses of problem types. I guess I'll wait for a little bit longer before deleting this post. It's a bit frustraiting to create a course on your own >.<